# AWS IAM policy for Billing & Cost Management

Tags: amazon-web-services

I try to make a policy to read Billing & Cost Management for Amazon AWS.

I created the new policy AccessJustBillingReports:

[image]

Then i attached this policy to a new user:

[image]

But if i loggin with this user and I open the Billing & Cost Management Dashboard i have no access!

[image]

What do i wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default IAM users cannot access billing as mentioned here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-permissions-ref.html#user-permissions

> Note These policies require that you activate IAM user access to the
>   AWS Billing and Cost Management console on the Account Settings
>   console page. For more information about activating IAM user access,
>   see Activate Access to the AWS Website.

If you login as root and scroll down a bit you'll notice a section about allowing IAM access like this:

[image]

Once you activate IAM access you should be able to access the billing section.